# How To Get SMPP DELIVERY REPORT

Tags: smpp

Using the client https://github.com/alexandr-mironov/php8-smpp. But while reading delivery report getting error " string(27) "ESME Already in Bound State". Looking for help from smpp experts.

```
<?php

use smpp\Client as SmppClient;
use smpp\transport\Socket;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$transport = new Socket(['xxxxxxxxxx'], xxxxx);
$transport->setRecvTimeout(60000);
$transport->open();

$smppClient = new SmppClient($transport);
$smppClient->debug = true;
$transport->debug = true;

try {
    $smppClient->bindReceiver('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
    $output = $smppClient->readSMS();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $output = $e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($output);
```

Looking for help from smpp experts.

Answer (score 0):

You receive the error "Already in Bound State" when you already have a bind a connexion. Let me explain a bit.

```
bind_transmitter/bind_transciever (outgoing from your server)
bind_response (incoming to your server)
bind_tranmitter/bind_transciever (outgoing from your server)
ESME_RALYBND (incoming to your server)
```

Maybe you should close the connexion with

```
$smppClient->close();
```

Before binding again.

Note that this answer is from a general knowledge, since i don't really master smpp with php.